# how to use :has in sass

Tags: css, sass

I need to add some styles if body has some element with .rtl class. 
How is possible to do it ?

```css
body:has(.app.rtl) {
   .blah {
       some: blah;
   }
}
```

This is something that I need

Comment: Not possible, at all. No preprocessor can help you here. Only Javascript. Things that cannot be achieved in CSS can of course also not be achieved using any pre-processor whatsoever.

Comment: does that not work? You probably don't need the `.app` (checking for an element with BOTH .app & .rtl classes). but its the right syntax.  Just make sure you put that at the end of the CSS so your attribute rules override the pre-existing ones.

Comment: @connexo is correct. I neglected to check if `:has` is out of the draft spec. Currently, no browsers implement it.

Comment: As they are saying, its not posible; you need to detect it and add a class to the elements that have that child

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want cannot be done using CSS since CSS has no parent selector and currently also no `:has` selector.

SASS cannot help you either since all SASS can do for you is make authoring CSS easier - in the end any pre-processor will compile your code to CSS which is the only thing the browser understands.
The only cross-browser solution here (still) is Javascript.

**Edit January 2023**: As of now, [Safari and Chrome/Chromium-based browsers (Edge, Brave, etc.) support `:has()`, and Firefox has support behind an experimental web platform features flag](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Your style is going to look like this:

```css
body:has(.app.rtl) .blah {
    some: blah;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The :has() CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the selectors passed as parameters (relative to the :scope of the given element), match at least one element.

The :has() pseudo-class takes a selector list as an argument. In the current specification :has is not marked as part of the live selector profile, which means it can not be used within stylesheets; only with functions like document.querySelector().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has