# SASS: Applying style based on presence of child element type

Tags: sass

I have a collection of tables nested within each other and background colors that are applied to each `<td>` in each row. I would ideally like to set the background as transparent on those `<td>` elements that themselves contain a child table, but I cannot identify how I'd specify this in SASS.

For example, I might have something like the following:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Point</th>
      <!-- This should be styled with a red background -->
      <td>0.025</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Point</th>
      <!-- This should be styled with a transparent background since it contains a table -->
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Sub-point</th>
               <!-- This should styled with a red background -->
               <td>0.75</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I can just have a naive selector like the following to apply the background on my `td` elements:

```
td {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

But it's not clear how I might then modify this (without adding another class to everything) to set the background to transparent if the `<td>` contains a `<table>`.

I'm ideally looking to avoid all use of JavaScript and only handle this through SASS.

### Attempt #1

At first, the pseudo-class `:has()` looked promising, but the guidance in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793922/how-to-use-has-in-sass) suggests it cannot be used in this scenario.

### Attempt #2

I could just specify a new class on the `<td>` containing the nested element and override the background style from there, but this isn't as clean an approach. I'll reserve this as the fallback solution, but a selector-based approach would be preferred.

Is this even possible?

Comment: No this is currently not possible. `:has()` would be a good candidate but is currently not supported by browsers. You need to implement your fallback solution and add a css class to all elements that have the role _table container_

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!